# Is "in obeyance" a typo in reportage of recent Supreme court proceedings?

Tags: legalese

The term "in obeyance" seemed strange in the story reported via online outlets.

Was this mis-reported, or did they mean "in abeyance", or is this an example of American English differing from the variant on the other side of the Atlantic?

> The high court said it would hold the Trump administration's request "in obeyance" to permit the district court judge to promptly consider other efforts by the administration
>
> [www.kuow.org](https://www.kuow.org/stories/supreme-court-refuses-to-block-lower-court-order-on-abortion-pills), quoting NPR, who at the time had the same wording.

But corrected copy at [NPR itself](https://www.npr.org/2020/10/08/921921889/supreme-court-refuses-to-block-lower-court-order-on-abortion-pills) uses *abeyance*. The word *obeyance* [is known](https://www.lexico.com/definition/obeyance) as meaning "obedience", so it did not seem to make sense in the original copy.

Comment: Other reports on this topic spell it 'abeyance'.

Comment: The two references are to the same article.  It's a simple spelling error.

Comment: This is an obvious typo (it is likely that there was at first a different typo, which was then 'corrected' by a spellchecker running without human supervision).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it was a typo in the reportage.

At time or writing the reply the [KUOW version online](https://www.kuow.org/stories/supreme-court-refuses-to-block-lower-court-order-on-abortion-pills) still says:

> The high court said it would hold the Trump administration's request "in obeyance" to permit the district court judge to promptly consider other efforts by the administration to "dissolve, modify, or stay" its previous order if "relevant circumstances have changed."

Thank you to @Andrew Leach for the tip to include a quote.  Both KUOW and NPR had that spelling at time of writing the OP.  However, it seems that by the time Andrew updated the OP, NPR had already corrected the typo in their version.

I am removing the north-american-english tag on the OP, as that in retrospect looks to probably be a red herring.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](https://www.supremecourt.gov/opinions/20pdf/20a34_nmjp.pdf) is the original text from the Supreme Court's opinion in the case, which uses "abeyance":

> Without indicating this Court’s views on the merits of the District Court’s order or injunction, a more comprehensive record would aid this Court’s review.  The Court will therefore hold the Government’s application in abeyance to permit the District Court to promptly consider a motion by the Government to dissolve, modify, or stay the injunction, including on the ground that relevant circumstances have changed.

"Abeyance" is "[a state of temporary inactivity](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abeyance)."  The Court is temporarily holding off on acting on the government's application in order to get more information.  "Obeyance" would not make sense here—the Court isn't ordering anyone to do anything, so there's nothing to obey.